# Why do rails migrations contain belongs_to, but not has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just spent an hour and half troubleshooting my app trying to figure out why

```
User.articles
```

was throwing errors. The models looked okay:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_many :articles
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

and

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :content, presence: true
  belongs_to :user  
  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories 
end
```

In the end, the problem was that the migration for articles did not have the line

```
t.belongs_to :user
```

Along the way, I also tried putting this line in the user migration

```
t.has_many :articles
```

but it threw an error.

Why do migrations only need the `belongs_to` side of the relationship and not `has_many`?

Comment: Are you confusing ActiveRecord models and migrations?  Models are a gateway into DB data via objects.  Migrations are used to help modify DB schemas.

Comment: Basically we keep the association key in the table where we have defined the belongs_to association. So `belongs_to` method in the migration will generate the `modelname_id` column in the table which is what we want. So there is no meaning for having the has_many method for migration. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Migrations provide a `.belongs_to` because that actually defines a column,  the foreign key linking the tables. On the other hand, `has_many` doesn't actually *do* anything to the table itself; including it in a migration would have absolutely non value or effect.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is on your part. The migrations doesn't have to have has many and belongs to because it's already defined in the models. For the relationship to work, generate a migration that adds user_id(integer) column to Articles table. 
i.e

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_articles
class AddUserIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```